# Is there any benefit to use cache if there is read miss for every access?

Tags: caching, memory-management, cpu-architecture

**Is there any benefit to use cache if there is read miss for every access?**

My question aims at a better understanding of caches.

Read miss for every access can also happen during cold start, am I right?

Comment: By searching your question in Google, I found this: https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/is-there-any-benefit-to-use-cache-if-there-is-read-miss-for-every-access-QTN_257721.htm

Comment: If you are talking about read cache and 100% percent read-miss, there should have no benefit.

Comment: read miss for every *read* access, or for every read and every write?  (Assuming a write-back cache which does an RFO and write-allocate, like typical modern CPUs.)

Comment: In a write-back cache, you might still potentially be able to have a write commit sooner and let the pipeline forget about it if you have a cache.  Although you get that just from having a store buffer when there aren't memory ordering barriers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing only reads and you miss *all levels of cache* on every read, then by definition caches didn't help. You paid extra in power and latency to check each level of cache, and extra power and (probably) latency to load a whole cache line of data which will never be used (by definition) except for the data you read since all your accesses miss.

You didn't say you are doing *only reads* though. So of course caches can help in the case that your reads all miss but some of your writes hit.

Perhaps you meant that the read-portion of all accesses, both reads and writes, misses - where the *read-portion* of a write is the *read-for-ownership* access present on most cache-based systems where a cache-line must be read into cache before (part of it) can be written. In that case, the cache probably also didn't help and probably hurt.

> Read miss for every access can also happen during cold start, am I right?

No, almost never. Some reads will miss, but those will bring in adjacent data on the same cache line which will often result in later hits (spatial locality). Many reads will go back to the same location even in a cold start (temporal locality) which will also often hit. Even beyond the dynamics of a single cache line, modern CPUs often offer hardware prefetching which will recognize certain access patterns and will bring in data before you need it which can result in hits even the first time you access a cache line.

Finally, on most general purpose hardware there you usually cannot decide to simply "not use the caches" so as a practical matter you pay the built-in costs of caching even if your hit rate is low.

That said, sometimes, when you *know* your access pattern you can provide hints to the CPU. For example, x86 CPUs provide "non-temporal store" instructions which essentially bypass the caches when used - meaning that the stored cache line won't be cached. This is useful not necessarily to speed up the store itself (which still largely pays the price of the cache hierarchy which is baked into the hardware), but to avoid polluting the cache with data the developer knows will not soon be accessed.

Comment: It does say "read miss for *every* access", which includes writes.  If we take that at face value, it implies a write-allocate policy (presumably write-back, not write-through), and the RFOs miss.  (And full-line accesses are impossible, so there's always a read on a write-miss).  Or maybe that's not exactly what it means.

Comment: Even if writes always miss, your write-back / eviction policy could try to group writes to the same DRAM page (e.g. writing back any other lines for the same page when one needs to be flushed), giving you out-of-order memory between commit to cache and write-back to DRAM.

Comment: @PeterCordes - well I wouldn't take it at face value: it seems entirely possible it means "read miss for every [read access]" rather than "read miss for every access [here talking about the RFO that happens for normal writes and assuming somehow that things like NT writes or full-line accesses don't occur]". Why would full-line accesses be impossible, anyway?

Comment: It is possible the cache eviction could try to be sympathetic with the DRAM access patterns, but I find it quite unlikely. The eviction behavior is mostly dominated my more more local concerns, like evicting a line from the required set (which already greatly reduces flexibility) and evicting things likely not be to be used soon (so some kind of LRU). Add to that CPU core is usually designed in a generic way, but many different memory configurations are possible, hidden beyond the memory controller: the parts on the CPU-side of the MC aren't likely to even know about the phys<->page mapping.

Comment: A full-line write wouldn't need to read, just invalidate other copies to get the line in M state.  I guess you might still call that an RFO.  Especially if hardware doesn't optimize that case.

Comment: The memory controller absolutely does do that kind of reorganization and often has a substantial buffering capability to support it, but you could argue that's part of the DRAM subsystem, not the cache one.

Comment: Right, on normal CPUs the eviction pattern is LRU.  But if you're considering designing a system where rule 1 of caching ("cache work") doesn't apply, might you still consider a cache?  Maybe yes if your only option is cache or no cache, and you have a dumb memory controller that you can't make smarter.  (If you read the first comment on the question, this was from an NVidia ASIC-design interview question.  I'm thinking in that context, about hypothetical weird designs that are unrealistic, but possibly better than some hypothetical cacheless design, **for specific unusual workloads**)

Comment: I meant "The OP is implying that full-line accesses are impossible" as one of the things it was possible to read into my literal interpretation of "access" including writes.

Comment: Sure, perhaps there are some memory ordering benefits to having a cache with a DRAM-aware eviction strategy even in a pure 100% read-miss scenario, although it sounds like a very difficult to support cross-cutting concern. E.g,. you'd way to organize it so that you can evict many potential lines, not just a few in the same set, to maximize the chance of evicting mutually DRAM-sympathetic lines around the same time. Plus you'd want to coordinate with other cores (that latter part is why the MC is much better at doing this, plus it knows exactly the DRAM arrangement).

Comment: Perhaps this is the outer level of cache, or on a chip with only one level of cache and a single "core" or equivalent.  We can basically assume it's not a CPU, because the 100% read miss scenario is not realistic (unless they're talking about during a limited time window, e.g. striding through a giant array, with code in a loop cached by a separate cache.)  But yes, it's a huge stretch, and being able to select lines from any set that are in the same page is tough.

Comment: Yes maybe, but the MC is still way better since it is the thing that is already naturally queuing the requests and doesn't have all the "act like a cache" cache requirements that would normally make this thing tough in a cache. If you add enough restrictions, like "dumb memory controller" sure you might be better off moving that logic into the LLC. Why not just design your LLC as just a giant CAM then totally dedicated to ordering memory accesses like a disk controller, since you know hits are impossible (and the line size should be the size of a single access).

Comment: Another really benefit if your access pattern is super weird with zero read or write hits and you want to design around it would be that the cache can absorb writes that might otherwise have to hang out in a more limited resource like a store buffer/line buffer all the way to DRAM. This doesn't seem to help the sustained throughput (since WB will be subject to the same limitation) and doesn't even really seem to help bursts with a normal WB cache, but if you had a cache that was constantly evicting dirty lines even when it wasn't forced to by an incoming fill, it could help bursts.

Comment: Actually there is an unrealistic case in which having a cache can be beneficial even when every read access is a technically miss. By having a cache, the memory controller will fetch a cache block of memory. With out-of-order execution, it is possible for the program to access all the data in the cache block before the cache block has been retrieved (so every read access would be a miss) while still (likely) having a latency benefit. The cache would be acting as an inefficient prefetch buffer (which is a specialized kind of cache).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - well strictly speaking I wouldn't really consider that a miss. I'd consider it something like "load hits pending cache line" or something like that. On x86 the performance counters in fact make exactly this distinction: you have all the various L1, L2, L3 hits, and you have a pure miss (the miss that brings in the cache line) and then you have "load hits LFB" for the loads that hit in the same line as the pending miss.

Comment: One might also argue that the presence of a cache justifies a higher computation speed. If the extremely cache unfriendly workload is extremely computation-intensive within registers, a processor with caches may be the best option since such workloads are probably not common enough to justify a specialized processor. (An economic/market consideration might gain points in an interview, aside from showing an ability to "think outside the box"/holistically.) Write buffering would facilitate memory access scheduling, removing writes to memory from the critical path.

Comment: Given the "every access" is a read miss, write hits would not be as beneficial as using a large write-combining buffer. Concerning the definition of miss, I was assuming "not a hit" (hits returns data with the normal cache latency) meant "a miss", but one could define "miss" to only include "cold misses" (which would even exclude prefetching if it is insufficiently timely). It sounds like Intel chose to define miss as "demand cold misses", i.e., excluding prefetch engine miss latency reduction (but presumably including software prefetches).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - yeah I see the basic categories as "pure hit" (with the expected latency based on the cache level it hits in) and "pure miss" which means a miss all the way to DRAM (or sometimes something like a remote cache in another socket without shared LLC), and then other thing is in a grey area in between, since the latency might vary all the way from pure miss all the way to almost as good as an L1 hit. Recent x86 allows you to track precisely actual latency, per-load, so you can categorize it that way if you want (e.g., consider a miss anything more than 20% worse than L3 latency).